# I can not install Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4 on VS 2013 express Desktop Edition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

This is my first post and I hope that it meets all of the requirements!

System:

```
 Windows 10

 VS 2013 Desktop Express
```

I am attempting to install Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4 but when I search through "Extensions and Updates" -> "Online" for "Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4," it can not locate the package.

I thought to myself, perhaps it is only in vs 2015 that you can find this or perhaps it is only in non-express editions. Thus, I turned to the Intergoogles! I found the following site:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

And there is support for vs2013 on this download! Yet, it says that it cannot locate any application on my machine that would use this if installed.

Can someone give me some guidance? Am I SOL if I am using VS 2013 but want access to the Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4? I am using EF6 if that helps.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Express edition do not support extensions, use Community edition 2013 instead. Julie Lerman has an updated version, that has been fixed to work with VS 2015 http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/installing-ef-power-tools-into-vs2015/

Comment: I have found that: 

1) Extensions and Updates does not list EF Power Tools anymore

2) VS2015 is not in the manifest file so you need to add it to the manifest file

Could you clarify on your post ErikEJ - Have you done this before? If so, did you find this to be true?

Comment: Ryan, you must use VS 2013 Community to see Extensions (and install them)